# alsamixer: "This sound device does not have any capture controls."

Tags: sound, 20.04, capture

Ubuntu 20.04.

I have a Behringer UCA200 audio interface that is supposed to be able both to send & to receive audio via USB to & from my computer. (I used this device several months ago, & know that it worked at that time.)

When I plug in the device, the device's audio codec is detected in the Ubuntu sound input device menu. Yet, when I select it, **(1) there is no sound input level** when I try to send audio to the computer – despite that neither my computer sound input control nor my audio generating device is muted, & the connection is fine – & **(2) no sound input volume control appears in the top right Ubuntu main menu,** next to the sound output volume & screen brightness controls.

I open up alsamixer in the terminal. I go to (F6) my USB sound card, then go to (F4) capture controls. I get the message, "**This sound device does not have any capture controls.**"

I have tried looking around on the internet, but other people who have had this issue have resolved it either by switching hardware, or by switching to a non-admin user. I do not have any alternative hardware I can use, & such hardware is expensive to buy in any case; & I do not have, want to create, or want to *have to* create, a new user on my computer just to record sound. I was able to use this device before fine, on my regular (admin) user, months ago; I would like to be able to do so again.

How do I resolve this issue?

*(Reposting question after upgrading from 18.04 or 18.10; issue has persisted after upgrade, & I did not receive any answers to my previous ask.)*

Comment: Hey, did you solve the problem? I get the same message and I fear that my HifiBerry AudioHat for the Raspberry Pi is dead.

Comment: You could try the softvol alsa plugin: https://alsa.opensrc.org/Softvol